# How to check whether a dictionary contains integer or string in python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I am new to python, I have a problem with string I have a dictionary like this `{'roads': '20' , 'rails': 'three'}`. I would like to find whether the values of the dictionary is an `int or str`. How do I do it?

```
input:
dict = {'roads': '20' , 'rails': 'three'}
Expected output:
dict = {'roads': 'int' , 'rails': 'object'}
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `dict` or you'll end up with very confusing bugs later when you try to call the builtin `dict` function!

Comment: @Samwise Ohh, Thanks will follow that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.isdigit()` to check is something is number

```py
dictionary = {'roads': '20' , 'rails': 'three'}

output = {k: 'int' if v.isdigit() else 'object' for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

```
{'roads': 'int', 'rails': 'object'}
```

Comment: but what if the value is float like 20.003 instead of 20

Comment: for safety you can use `v.replace('.', '').isdigit()` but then it is not `int` it is `float`